# How to GROUP BY column into months and COUNT per month?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to return number of rental orders each store as fulfilled per month. I want to show four columns; month, year, store ID, COUNT of rentals (per month). I have am able to return the month, year and store ID columns but the COUNT of rentals does not COUNT by month:

```
SELECT 
DATE_PART('month', r.rental_date) Rental_month, 
DATE_PART('year', r.rental_date) Rental_year, 
s.store_id, 
COUNT(r.rental_date) count_rentals 
FROM store s
JOIN staff staf
ON s.store_id = staf.store_id
JOIN payment pay
ON staf.staff_id = pay.staff_id
JOIN rental r
ON pay.rental_id = r.rental_id
GROUP BY r.rental_date, s.store_id
```

My output: 
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nwh4.png)

My desired output would look like this: 
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd9tI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually group by the month and year instead of the full date. Change your GROUP BY to -

```
GROUP BY  
       DATE_PART('month', r.rental_date),
       DATE_PART('year', r.rental_date),
       s.store_id,
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `date_part()`, I would recommend `date_trunc()`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', r.rental_date) as yyyymm, 
       st.store_id, 
       COUNT(*) as count_rentals 
FROM staff st JOIN
     payment p
     ON st.staff_id = p.staff_id JOIN
     rental r
     ON p.rental_id = r.rental_id
GROUP BY yyyymm, st.store_id;
```

Notes:

- `store` is not needed in the query.  The `store_id` is stored on the `staff` table.
- In Postgres, you can aggregate by a column alias.
- `date_trunc()` produces a date column, on the first day of the month.

Comment: 1x `date_drunc()` >>> 2 x `date_part()` in every respect.